# Android - Show progressdialog while executing task from another class

Tags: android, progressdialog

I'm trying to show a `ProgressDialog` while executing a task of another activity. I tried threats, uithreats and all things that I found but nothing helped me.

I only reach to do it with Toasts:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
user = new User(strLogin, strPwd);
if (globalVariable.getDB().isValidUser(user, globalVariable)) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Login ok", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    globalVariable.setUserLogged(true);
    globalVariable.setUser(user);
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainMenu.class));
} else {
    if(!globalVariable.getAuthorizedUser()) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Login not allowed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Login failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
```

What I want is to show `ProgressDialog` instead of `Toasts`.

So the problem seems to be that the method `isValidUser` it's in another activity and therefore it does not show dialog until the task ends.

I repeat that I had tried to put it inside `runOnUiThread` but did not the trick.

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried interface ?

Answer (score 0):

my suggestions is try the following.

1)

- change the method "isValidUser" to accept the failure
  callback,success callback   In the above code if the "isValidUser"
  true means then it goes to the if block otherwise it goes to the else
  block.   
  so makes the if it is true means then go to the success call
  back otherwise goes to the failure callback.   Before calling
  "isValidUser" star the progress bar and need to dismiss in the
  success/failure callback

Comment: But Where do I have to put it? and the progressdialog code too?

Comment: b4 calling the method "isValidUser" make ur progress dialog visible/show and in the callbacks (success/failure) make it is dismiss.I think this information is usefull for u

Comment: @Arnau if the answer is usefull means update the points for answer and it is the correct answer what u are searching means then mark as correct answer

Comment: the problem was that I was creating a new instance of a static class inside the isValidUser method,, and therefore it make exiting the main threat. Changing it solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming `globalVariable` is the activity validating the user. I would suggest making globalVariable a utility java class instead of an activity with a context. You can have your activities/ classes implement an interface which will have common methods you will use everywhere in your app, e.g. showing dialogs, toasts etc. Let us create an example called `BaseBehavior`.

```
public interface BaseBehavior {
  void showProgress();
  void hideProgress();
}
```

Lets make `globalVariable` implement the above interface

```
public class GlobalVariable extends Activity implements BaseBehavior{
    @Override
    public void showProgress(){
      // implement code to reveal progress dialog
    }

    @Override
    public void hideProgress(){
      // implement code to hide progress dialog
    }
}
```

Now in your code for any class that is implements that behavior can be called directly `globalvariable.showProgress()`. We could also have a ParentActivity which implements BaseBehavior and its methods, and we call that anywhere.

Another option is to use an AsyncTask for the globalVariable class.

```
public class GlobalVariable extends Activity {

// code

public void start(){
    new AsyncTaskRunner.execute()
}

private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<User, String, String> {

            private String resp;
            ProgressDialog progressDialog;

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(User... users) {
               // validateUser(user[0]);
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // showProgressDialog();
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // hideProgressDialog();
            }


            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text) {
                // End sequence

            }
    }
}
```

I hope these options help you achieve what you are looking for. :)

Comment: I tried to use async and when the script arrives at the line that calls the method from the other activity it returns an error: " java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"

Comment: Where are you calling the AsyncTask from?